# How to add some space between two specific bars of a pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

does anybody know how to get some space between the bars of my pgfplot? I want to add some text inbetween. I've tried adding an empty line in the data but it messes up the yticklabels (see attached screenshot). I would like to avoid using symbolic y coords because there are a lot of y coords (i've only included 6 in the MWE).
Perhaps there is an even simpler solution? Maybe using the groupplots library?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated! ✌

[image: space between bars]

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat}
GR  A   B   C   D
Göttingen\ (n=62)   1.6129  8.0645  45.1613 45.1613
Sachsen\ (n=90) 0   13.3333 40  46.6667
Coburg\ (n=24)  4.1667  37.5    37.5    20.8333
Göttingen\ (n=61)   3.2787  24.5902 37.7049 34.4262
Sachsen\ (n=89) 0   22.4719 42.6966 34.8315
Coburg\ (n=25)  8   48  16  28
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.14,
    /pgf/number format/assume math mode=true,
    title style={font=\bfseries\footnotesize\sffamily},
    every axis/.append style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title style={yshift=-1ex},
    xbar stacked,
    bar shift=0pt,
    bar width=6pt,
    scale only axis,
    width=9.75cm,
    y=1em,
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    minor x tick num=1,
    xtick style={black,thin},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]\tick\%},
    ytick style={draw=none},
    yticklabel style={xshift=0.5ex},
    enlarge y limits={abs=10pt},
    %/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,
    %nodes near coords,
    legend style={
        at={(0.5,-0.25)},
        anchor=north,
        legend columns=-1,
        draw=none,
        legend cell align=left},
    title=Attraktivität der Region zur Gewinnung von Jungmedizinern erhöhen durch…,
    ytick=data,
    y dir=reverse,
    yticklabels from table={Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat}{GR}]

    \addplot+[fill] table[x=A,y expr=\coordindex]{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat};
    \addplot+[fill] table[x=B,y expr=\coordindex]{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat};
    \addplot+[fill] table[x=C,y expr=\coordindex]{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat};
    \addplot+[fill] table[x=D,y expr=\coordindex]{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat};
    \legend{sehr unwichtig, eher unwichtig, eher wichtig, sehr wichtig}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
{} 0 0 0 0
```

in the data file, between each "group".

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat}
GR  A   B   C   D
Göttingen\ (n=62)   1.6129  8.0645  45.1613 45.1613
Sachsen\ (n=90) 0   13.3333 40  46.6667
Coburg\ (n=24)  4.1667  37.5    37.5    20.8333
{} 0 0 0 0 
Göttingen\ (n=61)   3.2787  24.5902 37.7049 34.4262
Sachsen\ (n=89) 0   22.4719 42.6966 34.8315
Coburg\ (n=25)  8   48  16  28
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.14,
    /pgf/number format/assume math mode=true,
    title style={font=\bfseries\footnotesize\sffamily},
    every axis/.append style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title style={yshift=-1ex},
    xbar stacked,
    bar shift=0pt,
    bar width=6pt,
    scale only axis,
    width=9.75cm,
    y=1em,
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    minor x tick num=1,
    xtick style={black,thin},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]\tick\%},
    ytick style={draw=none},
    yticklabel style={xshift=0.5ex},
    enlarge y limits={abs=10pt},
    %/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,
    %nodes near coords,
    legend style={
        at={(0.5,-0.25)},
        anchor=north,
        legend columns=-1,
        draw=none,
        legend cell align=left},
    title=Attraktivität der Region zur Gewinnung von Jungmedizinern erhöhen durch…,
    ytick=data,
    y dir=reverse,
    yticklabels from table={Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat}{GR}]

    \addplot+[fill] table[x=A,y expr=\coordindex]{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat};
    \addplot+[fill] table[x=B,y expr=\coordindex]{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat};
    \addplot+[fill] table[x=C,y expr=\coordindex]{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat};
    \addplot+[fill] table[x=D,y expr=\coordindex]{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat};
    \legend{sehr unwichtig, eher unwichtig, eher wichtig, sehr wichtig}

    \node at (50,3) {some text here};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Add space every n bars

If you need to add a space say every three bars, then you can modify the `y expr` a bit to achieve that automatically, without having to change the input.

To make modifications easier I defined a function with

```
declare function={
         Y(\x)={\x+floor(\x/3)};
       }
```

and used

```
y expr=Y(\coordindex)
```

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat}
GR  A   B   C   D
Göttingen\ (n=62)   1.6129  8.0645  45.1613 45.1613
Sachsen\ (n=90) 0   13.3333 40  46.6667
Coburg\ (n=24)  4.1667  37.5    37.5    20.8333
Göttingen\ (n=61)   3.2787  24.5902 37.7049 34.4262
Sachsen\ (n=89) 0   22.4719 42.6966 34.8315
Coburg\ (n=25)  8   48  16  28
Göttingen\ (n=62)   1.6129  8.0645  45.1613 45.1613
Sachsen\ (n=90) 0   13.3333 40  46.6667
Coburg\ (n=24)  4.1667  37.5    37.5    20.8333
Göttingen\ (n=61)   3.2787  24.5902 37.7049 34.4262
Sachsen\ (n=89) 0   22.4719 42.6966 34.8315
Coburg\ (n=25)  8   48  16  28
Göttingen\ (n=62)   1.6129  8.0645  45.1613 45.1613
Sachsen\ (n=90) 0   13.3333 40  46.6667
Coburg\ (n=24)  4.1667  37.5    37.5    20.8333
Göttingen\ (n=61)   3.2787  24.5902 37.7049 34.4262
Sachsen\ (n=89) 0   22.4719 42.6966 34.8315
Coburg\ (n=25)  8   48  16  28
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.14,
    /pgf/number format/assume math mode=true,
    title style={font=\bfseries\footnotesize\sffamily},
    every axis/.append style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
   declare function={
     Y(\x)={\x+floor(\x/3)};
   }]
\begin{axis}[
    title style={yshift=-1ex},
    xbar stacked,
    bar shift=0pt,
    bar width=6pt,
    scale only axis,
    width=9.75cm,
    y=1em,
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    minor x tick num=1,
    xtick style={black,thin},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]\tick\%},
    ytick style={draw=none},
    yticklabel style={xshift=0.5ex},
    enlarge y limits={abs=10pt},
    %/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,
    %nodes near coords,
    legend style={
        at={(0.5,-0.25)},
        anchor=north,
        legend columns=-1,
        draw=none,
        legend cell align=left},
    title=Attraktivität der Region zur Gewinnung von Jungmedizinern erhöhen durch…,
    ytick=data,
    y dir=reverse,clip=false,
    yticklabels from table={Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat}{GR}
]

    \addplot+[fill] table[x=A,y expr=Y(\coordindex)]{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat};
    \addplot+[fill] table[x=B,y expr=Y(\coordindex)]{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat};
    \addplot+[fill] table[x=C,y expr=Y(\coordindex)]{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat};
    \addplot+[fill] table[x=D,y expr=Y(\coordindex)]{Nachwuchsgewinnung.dat};
    \legend{sehr unwichtig, eher unwichtig, eher wichtig, sehr wichtig}

    \node at (50,3) {some text here};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So my approach (adding `{} {} {} {} {}`) was very close :)

Comment: @schmattes Yes. Just thought of an approach that doesn't require editing the input by the way, assuming there is always the same amount of bars in each group. See edited answer.

Comment: That's even better. But what do I have to change to get an empty line also above the first block?

Comment: @schmattes `ymin=-1`.